# IEEEtran problem in Appendix

Tags: appendices, ieeetran

I have to submit a paper to a conference which requires the IEEEtran 
class with the compsoc option. Everything is fine, except for the 
appendices.

1. The section command is just ignored in the appendix. I have to use the subsection command in order to have the headers shown.
2. When using the command "\subsection{Bla}" in the appendix, and referencing the subsection in text, the subsection is identified in Capital letters. But strangely, in the heads of the subsections, the identification is in decimal. How to change from decimal to capital letters? (only in the appendix. In the main text I want everything in decimal, as it is.)
3. I would like the numberings of lemmas and theorems in the appendix to depend on the sections of the appedix. Ex.lemmas in section A should be A.1 A.2,... Lemmas in section B should be B.1, B.2, ... But in the current version, the numbers in all sections of the appendix are of the form A.1 A.2 A.3... In other words the letters are not changing and the counter is not being reset. How to fix this?

[image: Result].

```
 \documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

 \begin{document}

 \section{First Section}

 \section{Second Section}

 \section{Third Section}

 \begin{itemize}
    \item See Appendix \ref{FirstAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{FirstSubsectionAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{SecondAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{ThirdAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{FourthAppendix}
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{testEntry}
      Test Ing, \emph{Testing a template}, 2017.
  \end{thebibliography}

  \appendix

  \subsection{First Appendix}
  \label{FirstAppendix}

  \subsubsection{First Subsection In Appendix}
  \label{FirstSubsectionAppendix}

  \subsection{Second Appendix}
  \label{SecondAppendix}

  \subsection{Third Appendix}
  \label{ThirdAppendix}

  \section{Fourth Appendix}
  \label{FourthAppendix}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: For multiple apendices, use \appendices instead of \appendix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that `\appendices` appears to be unique to `IEEEtrans` class.

```
 \documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

 \begin{document}

 \section{First Section}

 \section{Second Section}

 \section{Third Section}

 \begin{itemize}
    \item See Appendix \ref{FirstAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{FirstSubsectionAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{SecondAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{ThirdAppendix}
    \item See Appendix \ref{FourthAppendix}
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{testEntry}
      Test Ing, \emph{Testing a template}, 2017.
  \end{thebibliography}

  \appendices

  \section{First Appendix}
  \label{FirstAppendix}

  \subsection{First Subsection In Appendix}
  \label{FirstSubsectionAppendix}

  \section{Second Appendix}
  \label{SecondAppendix}

  \section{Third Appendix}
  \label{ThirdAppendix}

  \section{Fourth Appendix}
  \label{FourthAppendix}

  \end{document}
```

[image: demo]